# Integral of dataserie

Tags: javascript, math

Given a dataset likes this:

`[[timestamp1, value1], [timestamp2, value2], ...,[timestampN, valueN]]`

Is there a Javascript library which be able to calculate the area of the curve?. To put it another way, it is possible to calculate the integral of the curve? I have found libraries which given an equation formule, returns the integral of that, but in this case I have the dataserie and I would like to get the area from that data without generate an approximate equation.

Comment: If you make assumptions about the form of the function, you can fit the function to the data and then compute the integral of the function. But more simply, you could fit a spline (let's say a cubic spline) to the data and integrate that; I'm pretty sure that's a solved problem. But even more simply, just assume each datum represents a bar of height value[k] centered at timestamp[k] and add up the bars. It is going to be hard to find something substantially more accurate than that.

Comment: [Any algorithms would do.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration#Methods_for_one-dimensional_integrals) Since we have discrete points on a 2D plane, we can simply compute the area as trapezoids, or you can assume the curve to be differentiable and use a more sophisticated algorithm. It all depends on what your assumptions of the data are.

Comment: What curve? I just see datasets...

Answer (score 1):

Any numerical integration scheme could do this.  The simplest way is Simpson's rule.  You need to make sure that the array values are sorted in ascending order of timestamp.

Once you do that, it's a simple sum:

```
var integral = 0.0;
for (i = 2; i <= N; ++i) {
    // function delta takes two timestamp parameters and calculates 
    // differences as time units (hours, minutes, seconds or milliseconds)
    // not as simple as subtraction 
    var dt = delta(timestamp[i-1], timestamp[i]);  
    integral += (value[i]+value[i-1])*dt;  // area of the trapezoid
}
integral /= 2.0;
```